# How can I get my dapper result to be a List?

Tags: c#, dapper

Why I can't add a `.ToList()` on this? The only thing Intellisense is allowing is `.ToString()`.

```
//..
string sqlQuery = "SELECT sum(SellingPrice) as SellingPrice, sum(MarkupPercent) as MarkupPercent, sum(MarkupAmount) as MarkupAmount FROM ProfitMargins WHERE QuoteId in @QuoteId group by multiplier";
{
    List<ProfitMargin> profitMargin = (List<ProfitMargin>)await conn.QueryAsync<List<ProfitMargin>>(sqlQuery, new { QuoteId = QuoteIds.ToArray()})  //would like to add .ToList() here;

    return profitMargin;
}
//..
```

UPDATE

I believe the problem has to do with conn.queryasync  (conn is context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString) instead of context.Database.SqlQuery

Comment: IIRC the generic parameter should be `ProfitMargin`, not `List<ProfitMargin>`

Comment: You need "using System.Linq" to get Intellisense to show the Linq extension methods such as ToList()

Comment: For what object you try to call function ToList()?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try changing to this.

```
List<ProfitMargin> profitMargin = (await conn.QueryAsync<ProfitMargin>(sqlQuery, new { QuoteId = QuoteIds.ToArray()})).ToList();
```

Or

```
var results = await conn.QueryAsync<ProfitMargin>(sqlQuery, new { QuoteId = QuoteIds.ToArray()});
List<ProfitMargin> profitMargin = results.ToList();
```

I think you are hitting the `Task` object with your attempts at calling `.ToList()`

Comment: why can't I do .tolistasync?  - the .tolist is working now.

Comment: `.QueryAsync<t>` returns a `Task<t>` object not a `t` object. Task objects have their own properties etc on them, one of which is `Result` which holds your `IEnumerable<ProfitMargin>` object when execution is complete. Basically you would be trying to call `.ToList()` on a `Task` which doesn't have a `.ToList()` function defined. `await` interacts a little weird with parenthesis. Think of the `await` like a cast, to operate on what you are casting to, you have to surround the whole thing with parenthesis.

Comment: `QueryAsync` returns a sequence of type, as per the answer above the response type would be an `IEnumerable<IList<ProfileMargin>>` not `List<ProfileMargin>`

SOLUTION: `List<ProfitMargin> res = await conn.QueryAsync<ProfitMargin>(sqlQuery, new { QuoteId = QuoteIds.ToArray()})).ToList()` as stated below

Comment: need Dapper QueryToListAsync<t>

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
List<ProfitMargin> profitMargin = new List<ProfitMargin>(await conn.QueryAsync<ProfitMargin>(sqlQuery, new { QuoteId = QuoteIds.ToArray()}));
```

or

```
List<ProfitMargin> profitMargin = (await conn.QueryAsync<ProfitMargin>(sqlQuery, new { QuoteId = QuoteIds.ToArray()})).ToList();
```

As @Amy stated, you need to use

```
conn.QueryAsync<ProfitMargin>(sqlQuery, new { QuoteId = QuoteIds.ToArray()}))
```

which returns a `Task<IEnumerable<ProfitMargin>>` thus upon awaiting evaluates to an `IEnumerable<ProfitMargin>`.